# Xml vs table databases in reusable software

Tags: xml, database, reusability

I am building a web tool require databases this database I must to take it from the database of system which I build the tool within it  , I did not want to build my tool to running in one system , I want do reusable software  (General tool ) ... the software engineering said the tool must be reused in other system ... so I decided to put  the extract database from database of system in xml file rather than I write query to extract database from  tables of databases of system (like Oracle , sql server ) , my question is when I want generalization and reusable tool what should I use to store my needed database in xml file or (Oracle , sql server database ) ? Is my decision true of not ?

EDIT : 
each system has databases table s ( Oracle , sql ) different from system to another for example : the first system has ( Oracle database ) and the second system has (sql server database ) to avoid write different query aspect (Oracle , sql) represented to extract database I was think to do is to put structural database in xml files So whatever the representation of databases in system I did not care because I use structural database store in xml file  (that was I think ... But I did not knew if my decision is true or false .... I didn't knew if use xml file insurer the reusable tool or not )

Comment: I did not understand your problem, so I'll put a little comment.
Generally avoid XML, I do not like it as something scalable.
If it's a database you'd rather use a database ... if you're looking for something small and easy to use try SQLlite.

Answer (score 0):

XML isn't a database. XML is good to move data from one system to another system.